# how to separate each and every column in the mysql db row ? in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, laravel-5.1

Controller

```
public function getback(Request $request)
{

    $chart = DB::table('BirthChart_1')
             ->where('FileId', 123)
             ->get();

            return $chart;

}
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/getback

output be like

> [{"FileId":123,"k1":3,"k2":4,"k3":null,"k4":null,"k5":null,"k6":5,"k7":null,"k8":null,"k9":null,"k10":null}]

I want to get access each and every column  separately , I put like that

```
return $chart["k1"];
```

got error ...

> my main task is take the each column's data send into script

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: I want separate answer for each column example k1=3 -> I would separate 3 and so on @charlietfl

Comment: I mean what is expected data structure? Take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Thank @charlietfl. I want result to be (3,4,null,null,null,5,null,null,null,null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller be like

```
public function getback(Request $request)
{


    $chart = DB::table('BirthChart_1')
             ->where('FileId', 123)
             ->get();



            foreach ($chart as $key ) {
                $f[] = [$key->k1,$key->k2,$key->k3,$key->k4,$key->k5,$key->k6,$key->k7,$key->k8,$key->k9,$key->k10];

            }

            return response()->json($f);
}
```

output of the result

```
[[3,4,null,null,null,5,null,null,null,null]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you're getting an array of rows, try:

```
return $chart[0]["k1"];
```